# Getting a return value from php with backbone.js

Tags: php, codeigniter, backbone.js

Hello i have the  following codeIgniter Controller php code that saves a Backbone Model to the server

```
public function generate()
    {
       //Converts JSON object to array
       $data = decode(TRUE);
       $this->load->library('db_models',$config=array('localhost', 'user', '343boys'));
       $data = $this->db_models->getFields($data['database'],$data['table']);
       //Converts $data to JSON object
       $data = encode($data);
       //Problem is here how to i assign this data back to my model.
       return $data;

    }
```

I have created a JSON helper decode and encode that that converts JSON to array and array to JSON respectively. This have no proble as i have tested them with firebug.
the code works alright when saving but i have hit a snag when i try to retrieve the return $data; after the function has finished saving.

My Model is like so

```
var Table = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults:{
       'table':'mine',
       'database':'db'
},
        urlRoot : '/campusfeed/index.php/welcome/generate'

    });
model.save();
```

So how would i go about saving a value through a function and retrieving what the function returns not neccessarilt in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

```
model = new Table({
  table: 'yours'
  ,database: 'database'
});

model.save(null, {success: success});
```

or

```
model = new Table();
model.set({
  table: 'yours'
  ,database: 'database'
});
model.save(null, {success: success});
```

or

```
model = new Table();
model.save(
  {
    table: 'yours'
    ,database: 'database'
  }
  ,{success: success}
);
```

The first object you pass to `model.save()` is the hash of properties you want to change. The second param is the options hash. The `success` callback receives three paramters. The updated model, the response from the server, and the xhr object. The success function could be defined this way:

```
function success(model, response, xhr) {
  console.log('model saved', model, response, xhr);
}
```